# facebook API add photo

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I need to post a Bitmap to Facebook wall along with a message and url link.

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos, there are 4 parameters to add a photo to Facebook album:

`source`, `message`, `place`, `no_story`.

However, I was recommend to use a code like this:

```
Bitmap bm = ...;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
final byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();

postParams.putByteArray("photo", data);
postParams.putString("message", "My message here");
postParams.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");

Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

... and this code works fine except it does not show the link ("http://www.google.com") on the wall.

I have three questions:

1. Why does `postParams.putByteArray("photo", data)` work? There's no `photo` parameter according to documentation (see above).
2. If it is impossible to use `link` parameter, how does SLComposeViewController class (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) work? It has `- (BOOL)addURL:(NSURL *)url` method.
3. If it is possible to use `link` parameter, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found answers to questions (2) and (3). It appeared to be very simple: do not use `link`, just append it to `message`:

```
postParams.putByteArray("photo", data);
postParams.putString("message", "My message here" + " " + "http://www.google.com");
//postParams.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");
```

As for my question (1), it is still unclear for me: why does `postParams.putByteArray("photo", data);` work fine instead of `postParams.putByteArray("source", data);`? The documentation say nothing about `photo` parameter.